# PRAW: Python Reddit API Wrapper not working

Tags: python, pip, easy-install, praw, reddit

I'm trying to make a Reddit bot, except I cannot even use the following simple example, nor the examples PRAW has in their docs.

The following code

```
import praw
r = praw.Reddit(user_agent="some useragent text")
r.login()
```

returns the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "savageAxeBot.py", line 3, in <module>
    r = praw.Reddit(user_agent="some useragent text")
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/praw-4.0.0b21-py2.7.egg/praw/reddit.py", line 101, in __init__
    raise ClientException(required_message.format(attribute))
praw.exceptions.ClientException: Required configuration setting 'client_id' missing. 
This setting can be provided in a praw.ini file, as a keyword argument to the `Reddit` class constructor, or as an environment variable.
```

UPDATE: I've gotten both my client ID and secret. I managed to get the above code (exactly as shown) to work on Fedora 24, not could not get it to work on either Raspbian or Mac OS X.

PRAW seems easier to use from python than the Reddit API, so I would prefer to stick with it. Also, it appears that `login()` is depreciated, so how can I use OAuth2 (or whatever it is called)?

Note: I installed PRAW using `easy_install praw`, since `pip install praw` wasn't working. I tried using `pip` on both Mac OS X 10.12 and Raspbian, and neither worked. Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like you need to obtain a client_id and provide it to the library. The documentation will probably tell you how. Failing that, read through the source code. Actually, looks like the answer is on Reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/redditdev/comments/4bwdpx/praw_4_what_do_i_input_for_client_id_and_client/ You need to register your app and get an ID and Secret.

Comment: @Basic Thanks for your comment! I have acquired both the id and the secret, except I can not for the life of me figure out how to use them. How would I go about this? I mentioned in my question that I am a python newbie, except an editor took it out. Thanks in advance! (If you help me and your advice works, I'll accept your answer (if you create one) and I will give you a rep. bonus.)

Comment: @Basic the issue is that there is no documentation for praw 4; if there was I most likely wouldn't have asked the question.

Comment: No documentation you say? http://praw.readthedocs.io/en/praw4/ That is, and has been, linked at the top of the repository for a number of months now.

Comment: Specifically, read the [Getting started](http://praw.readthedocs.io/en/praw4/pages/getting_started.html#get-a-reddit-instance) page which shows you how to create read-only and read-write Reddit objects.

Comment: @bboe Well shoot I'm stupid. Didn't see it. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @Basic If you put that link in an answer, I'll accept it. It worked.

Comment: @FlareCat you're not stupid. Sorry if my comment came across as terse. The README was confusing in that it said "At this time the majority of the documentation has not yet been updated to PRAW4." and it did not link to the correct version of the documentation. I made a change which I hope makes the PRAW4 documentation more visible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Promoted/expanded from a comment]

As pointed out by @bboe, the PRAW docs can be located [here](http://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) ¹.

Specifically, you want the [Getting Started](http://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pages/getting_started.html#get-a-reddit-instance) ¹ page which walks you through instantiating a Reddit object in read-only or read/write mode.

¹ PRAW 4 documentation is no longer available onlne, so I've updated the links to track the latest version.

Comment: Both links are broken.

Comment: @darol100 Thanks, both should be fixed now. Apparently PRAW 4 documentation is no longer available online, so I'm not pointing at latest